# Adding class atribute to wp_nav_menu ul

Tags: menus

**Update:** this was caused by the fact that i didn't have a menu created in the menu page.

I want to add a class to the ul of wp_nav_menu.
I tried this code:

```
<?php

$defaults = array(
    'menu_class'      => 'menu',
    'items_wrap'      => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
);

wp_nav_menu( $defaults );

?>
```

According to wordpress codex changing the *menu* from 'menu_class'      => '*menu*', should change the class of the ul, but instead it changes the class of the div wrapping the ul.

`<div class="this class is changed"><ul><li class="page_item page-item-2"><a href="http://domain.tld/">Sample Page</a></li></ul></div>`

Comment: For 1 nav menu item?

Comment: For all ul in the navigation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`menu_class` is indeed what changes the `ul` class. What's happening there is you didn't set which menu to use:

- `wp-admin/nav-menus.php?action=locations`

Comment: I figured it out, i didn't add suport for menus in functions.php, once i did and created a menu in the menu pages it worked as it should.